# Reference request for Calderón-Zygmund theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, harmonic-analysis

I have studied the basic topics concerning Fourier Series and measure theory. I feel it's time to move to some more advanced topics. Are you aware of any introductory and readable book/lecture notes of Calderón-Zygmund theory? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fourier Analysis by Javier Duoandikoetxea ... even if called Fourier analysis, is exactly what you are asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 7 of the following text is a nice introduction:

Muscalu, C., & Schlag, W. (2013). Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis (Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9781139047081.

This one was written by an authority on the subject:

Stein, E. M. (1970). Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions (Vol. 2). Princeton university press.

Comment: Are they readable without too much background on the  subject?

Comment: I think so. You said you have studied Fourier series and measure theory. If you understand the first 3 chapters of Muscalu and Schlag, you should be able to read chapter 7, although it's not an easy text in general. I haven't read much of Stein's book, but Stein is a master expositor.

Comment: Then I should be able to read it. Thank's!